# Sending suppressions from SendGrid

Tags: python, php, sendgrid

How can I make a script to automatically get suppressions(Bounce, Spam, Invalid and Block)  from SendGrid and send them by email to anyone that I want to? I was considering using SendGrid api but I am not sure if it possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a list of [bounces](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/bounces-api/retrieve-all-bounces), [blocks](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/blocks-api/retrieve-all-blocks), [spam reports](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/spam-reports-api/retrieve-all-spam-reports) and [invalid emails](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/invalid-e-mails-api/retrieve-all-invalid-emails) via the respective APIs.

You can also use the [Event Webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event) to receive events about your emails including if an email was dropped, bounced, blocked or reported as spam.